# Java use protected method of superclass in copy constructor of subclass

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a protected method (I don't want this method to be seen outside Superclass or it subclasses). I want to use it in copy constructor, but I can't. Code:

```
public class Superclass {
    protected HashMap<Object, Object> getData() {
        return new HashMap<>();
    }
}

public class Subclass extends Superclass {
    public Subclass(Superclass abstractClass) {
        init(abstractClass);
    }

    private void init(Superclass abstractClass) {
        //ERROR!!! getData has protected access in Superclass
        for (Map.Entry<Object, Object> entry : abstractClass.getData().entrySet()) {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

How can I overcome this problem if I still want to create Subclass object from Superclass object without exposing getData() method?

**EDIT** Classes are in different packages!

Comment: I am getting a bunch of other errors with that code, but not the one you mentioned

Comment: Sorry, I wrote this code to be similar to my real project code, but did not actually compiled it. I will edit it for it to actually be compilable.

Comment: @DeGiz and, I suspect that the two classes are in different packages, right? That would be an important information!

Comment: Yes, packages are different.

Comment: You have a problem to start with: you shouldn't call instance methods in constructors

Comment: But I don't to want to access field directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**While in the same package** the following works fine for me:

*Superclass*:

```
public class Superclass {
    protected List<String> getData() {
        return Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
    }
}
```

*Subclass*:

```
public class Subclass extends Superclass {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Superclass superObject = new Superclass();
    Subclass subObject = new Subclass(superObject);
}

    public Subclass(Superclass abstractClass) {
        //ERROR!!! getData has protected access in Superclass
        for (String entry : abstractClass.getData()) {
            System.out.println(entry);
        }
    }
}
```

Mind you, I'm not sure that's what you're actually trying to do. Why are you passing an instance of `Superclass` in the constructor of `Subclass` for example? Also, you had a `HashMap` rather than a `List`, but HashMaps aren't `Iterable`, so you can't use the extended for loop on them.

**However:**
If those classes are in different packages, things change. Look at the language specifications; in [§6.6.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.1) it says:

> [I]f the member or constructor is declared protected, then access is permitted only when one of the following is true:
>
> - Access to the member or constructor occurs from within the package containing the class in which the protected member or constructor is declared.
> - Access is correct as described in §6.6.2.

And [§6.6.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.2) states:

> A protected member or constructor of an object may be accessed from outside the package in which it is declared only by code that is responsible for the implementation of that object.

Now, as calling a function in an init method is **not** considered *responsible for implementation*, you may not access the member here. Sorry, that's how the language works.

Comment: Note that OP uses different packages - when the two classes are in the same package it works, but `protected` denies access from other packages

Answer (score 3):

You tried to access a method, before creating an instance. The instance is not yet fully initialized.

Calling methods of objects that are being constructed from their own constructor can result in unexpected behavior as the objects are not initialized consistently until the constructor finishes.

Comment: `bstractClass.getData()` in the sub class Constructor

Comment: But `abstractClass` is a parameter, how do you know it has not been fully initialized yet? He does not reference `this`!

Comment: @Andreas please put your comments together in answer and I will gladly accept it. I did not thought that packages do make difference.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing a protected method from a class in a different package is not possible - see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html. The fact that you are inheriting from `Superclass` does not count, since you are trying to call the method on a reference to `Superclass`, **not** on the base class itself.

So, what you are trying to do does not work - if it would, it would break Java's access control: you could then simply inherit from any class and implement a method which takes a super class reference as parameter, and then access all protected methods of the super class (you can, of course, still *inherit* from the base class and access the protected members of the superclass, even cross-package).

If `getData()` is a method which needs to be called from another package, you need to make it public.

On a side note, you should probably rethink your design - is it really necessary to pass a reference to a `Superclass` object in the `Subclass` constructor?